# How to split comma separated values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have text-box inside a gridview and i am performing and insert statement looping through every row in my gridview.  My issue now is that i can have multiple names in the text-box like this:

```
John Carter, Mike David, John Edward,
```

so how can i split and insert each individual name into my table with the same ID? For instance, if the current row has ID =12 then my table will look like this:

```
ID      Full_Name
12     John Carter
12     Mike David
12     John Edward
```

here is my code:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label ID = row.FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;                
                TextBox myUID = row.FindControl("txt_UID") as TextBox;
                string Full_Name = Request.Form[row.FindControl("txt_UID").UniqueID];

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"if not exists(select ID from myTable where ID = @ID)
                                   insert into myTable(ID, Full_Name) values(@ID, @Full_Name)
                                    else update myTable set Full_Name =@Full_Name where ID =@ID";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Full_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Full_Name.ToString();

                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
}
```

Comment: What is the ID? If it is the Primary Key of your table that would be impossible.

Comment: no it is different ID.

Comment: You'll need to capture the comma-delimited elements via a call to String.Split against Full_Name, and given the way you're code is set up, you'll need to loop through your insert code for each resultant value.

Comment: Thanks David, but i could not get it to work

Comment: Let me try to mod your code above and post it as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very rough/quick notion of what I'm suggesting in the comment above. have not had a chance to test it.

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label ID = row.FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label;                
                TextBox myUID = row.FindControl("txt_UID") as TextBox;
                string Full_Name = Request.Form[row.FindControl("txt_UID").UniqueID];

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"if not exists(select ID from myTable where ID = @ID)
                                   insert into myTable(ID, Full_Name) values(@ID, @Full_Name)
                                    else update myTable set Full_Name =@Full_Name where ID =@ID";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                foreach(string currentName in Full_Name.Split(','))
                {
                    if (currentName!="")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Full_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currentName;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }
                con.Close();

            }
}
```

Comment: what about in case there is only one name in the text like this: John Edward,  will this work with this code?

Comment: i am getting this error: 'string' does not contain a definition for CurrentName

Comment: I also realize you can simply assign the parameter values directly rather than clear/add on each iteration, but I won't risk confusing the issue at this point.

Comment: i am getting this error: "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"  so it seems that it inserted the first name but failed to insert the rest.

Comment: Okay, @moe, one moment and I"ll fix it.

Comment: @moe, believe I've got it fixed for you.

Comment: it is inserting into the database but the split is not working.  I can see all names in one row so it is splitting at all.  thx

Comment: @Moe That's very odd - there's nothing I can see in the code now that would explain why you're seeing the entire, unsplit string in one record. The unsplit string is never involved in the update/insert. You're actually still seeing "name1, name2, name3" in the database record??

Comment: If you're still seeing the unsplit record in the databse, I would step through the debugger and see what is being generated within the foreach loop that takes the results from the Full_Name.Split(',') call. Are you sure you replaced the parameter value assignment wihtin the loop from Full_Name to currentName?

Comment: yes, that is what i did but still seeing the entire record like name1,name2 etc.  it is weird

Comment: Without seeing your code its very difficult to guess what's wrong. As I mentioned in the previous comment, I would step through the debugger and ensure currentName is getting the expected values from Split. Are you sure you have a true comma as the delimiter and not some other character?

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "John Carter, Mike David, John Edward,";
string[] names = str.Split(',');
foreach (string name in names)
{
    if (name.Equals(""))
        continue;

    ///dbstuff
    ///insert into myTable(ID, Full_Name) values(@ID, @name)
    ///etc, etc
}
```

This *strongly* assumes that ID is not a primary key.  As long as ID is not unique and not a key, this sort of methodology should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the query with the use of loop like this

```
foreach (string name in Full_Name.Split(','))
{
  cmd.CommandText = @"if not exists(select ID from myTable where ID = @ID)
                        insert into myTable(ID, Full_Name) values(@ID, @Full_Name)
                      else update myTable set Full_Name =@Full_Name where ID =@ID";

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Full_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name

  cmd.Connection = con;
  con.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```